# How to change wicket DatePicker markup?

Tags: java, date, datepicker, wicket, markup

I'm trying to change DatePicker's HTML markup in Apache Wicket. 
What I have for now:

```
public CustomDateTextField(final String id, IModel<T> model, Class<T> type, String modelPath) {
        super(id, model, type, modelPath);
        addDatePicker();

}
```

And this one uses default markup. For example, to initialize this one I use this Java code:

```
CustomDateTextField<?> textField = new CustomDateTextField(field, model.bind(field), pathPrefix + "." + field);
```

And this HTML markup:

```
<input wicket:id="date" name="date" type="text"  size="10" maxlength="10" />
```

But for testing automation I want to have unique ID available on UI. I mean, if I will inspect my datePicker on UI now, I will have:

```
<img style="cursor: pointer; border: none;" id="date53Icon" src="resources/org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker/icon1.gif" alt="" title="">
```

But I need to make this specific datePicker unique. For example, I can add to html name="apocalypseDate", but to do that I need somehow extract the markup. And now i'm quite confused how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi,

I don't understand what do you mean exactly with 'make this specific datePicker unique'. Do you need to assign a unique id to img tag?

Comment: I mean that I want to have few datePickers on page, but with different ID or Name. So I want to be able to see that when I'm inspecting element. For example I want to have 2 datepickers: 1. name="startDate"; 2. name="endDate". 
What I have now - generated id, which is changing with page refresh. I want to make it constant.

Comment: ok, thank you for your clarification. In this case I would also suggest to set the id with setMarkupId or, alternatively, you could use an attribute modifier (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is always the component id of the component and *Icon* (that's why you get `date53Icon`), defined in `DatePicker#getIconId`. Unfortunately this method is final, so you can't override it. But you can set the id of the textField:

```
textField.setMarkupId("textField");
textField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

The id of the image will then be `textFieldIcon`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could set name attribute like this:

```
textField.add(AttributeModifier.replace("name", "fixedValue"));
```

Comment: That doesn't work in that case. He wants to set the id of the image generated by the `DatePicker` and not the id/name of the `TextField`.